# Procedure Not Updating DB When Executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures, procedure

I have a two simple update statement that work when run individually.  But I would like to put them in a procedure so I can define two roles and an effective date for each.

The update statements are:

```
UPDATE DTSMobileDetail
SET DTSMD.MobileID=294
FROM DTSMobileDetail DTSMD
Inner Join DTSDetail DTSD on DTSMD.ShiftID=DTSD.ShiftID
Inner Join LocationDetail LD on DTSD.LocationID=LD.LocationID
Inner Join Accounts Acct on LD.AccountID=Acct.AccountID
Inner Join CenterDetail CD on Acct.CenterID=CD.CenterID
Inner Join IDViewCollectionOp CO on CD.CenterID=CO.CodeID
WHERE CO.CodeID in ('108','110','106','107')
and DTSMD.MobileID=700

-- Update Futre Drives with new Staff Template
UPDATE DSMD
SET DSMD.MobileID=294
FROM DriveMaster DM
Inner Join DriveShiftDetail DSD on DM.DriveID=DSD.DriveID
Inner Join DriveShiftMobileDetail DSMD on DSD.ShiftID=DSMD.ShiftID
Inner Join CenterDetail CD on DM.CenterID=CD.CenterID
Inner Join IDViewCollectionOp CO on CD.CenterID=CO.CodeID
WHERE DSMD.MostRecent=1
And CO.CodeID in ('108','110','106','107')
And DSMD.MobileID=700
And DM.FromDateTime >= '02/19/2015'
```

What I'd like to accomplish is have the new mobile ID (@NewRoleName) and old mobile ID (@OldRoleName) set to variables and also the date in the 2nd update to @EffectiveDate.

I have tried to insert the Updates into a procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--CREATE PROCEDURE CA66_Staff_Role_Change
Alter PROCEDURE CA66_Staff_Role_Change
-- Declare new role, old role, effective drive date variables
@OldRoleName int,
@NewRoleName int,
@EffectiveDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Update Accounts with new Staff Template
UPDATE DTSMD
SET DTSMD.MobileID=@NewRoleName
FROM DTSMobileDetail DTSMD
Inner Join DTSDetail DTSD on DTSMD.ShiftID=DTSD.ShiftID
Inner Join LocationDetail LD on DTSD.LocationID=LD.LocationID
Inner Join Accounts Acct on LD.AccountID=Acct.AccountID
Inner Join CenterDetail CD on Acct.CenterID=CD.CenterID
Inner Join IDViewCollectionOp CO on CD.CenterID=CO.CodeID
WHERE CO.CodeID in ('108','110','106','107')
and DTSMD.MobileID=@OldRoleName

-- Update Futre Drives with new Staff Template
UPDATE DSMD
SET DSMD.MobileID=@NewRoleName
FROM DriveMaster DM
Inner Join DriveShiftDetail DSD on DM.DriveID=DSD.DriveID
Inner Join DriveShiftMobileDetail DSMD on DSD.ShiftID=DSMD.ShiftID
Inner Join CenterDetail CD on DM.CenterID=CD.CenterID
Inner Join IDViewCollectionOp CO on CD.CenterID=CO.CodeID
WHERE DSMD.MostRecent=1
And CO.CodeID in ('108','110','106','107')
And DSMD.MobileID=@OldRoleName
And DM.FromDateTime >= @EffectiveDate

END
GO
```

And when I try to execute the statement with:

```
Exec CA66_Staff_Role_Change 294,700,'02/19/2015'
Go
```

It tells me it executed successfully, but when I check the records, nothing has been updated.

Any suggestions on what I could be missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Do a `SELECT` statement with your parameters and see if anything comes back.  My guess is it couldn't find anything to update - which wouldn't impact the result of the procedure call (it would still report as successful, as it did not error).

Comment: When I change it a SELECT statement looking for the @OldRoleName, I see 176 accounts that have it.  And for Drives (2nd statement), there are only 2 drives with the old role name. And then when I execute the procedure, I still see the 176 accounts with the old role name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing `294` to the @oldRoleName actually in your original update statement, `294` should be the new rolename

so pass the values correctly

```
Exec CA66_Staff_Role_Change 700,294,'02/19/2015'
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks. Can't believe I missed that.